# Listen for a UIView's touchesBegan/touchesEnded within an NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I have an NSObject that accepts a UIView in the init function, and assigns it as a property. The functionality of this behavior class depends on how long the UIView is pressed, using touchesBegan/touchesEnded.

I want to encapsulate this touchesBegan/touchesEnded logic within the NSObject class, in an effort to make this behavior class more modular. Currently, the touchesBegan/touchesEnded functionality is in the UIViewController class, and passed to the behavior.

Is it possible to override and/or "listen" for touchesBegan/Ended in the NSObject class?

Comment: Why aren't you subclassing from UIView instead of using NSObject wrapper?

Comment: @lyuna I'd like to be able to add this behavior to any UIView to "enhance" it, instead of having to replace it with this subclassed view. Being able to override the touch events in an NSObject class would allow me to do that. But you're right, it may be the case that I need to subclass UIView instead. I think this question is really asking, is this possible, and if so, how can it be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom touch handling logic you should subclass `UIGestureRecognizer`. You can then add it to any view.

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/) for gesture recognizers and the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html).